# Find the joint pdf of $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$, where $(X_1, X_2)$ has a uniform distribution in the unit circle.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, uniform-distribution, density-function

I recently faced such a task:
[image]

If I understand correctly, then

$$f_{X_1, X_2}(s,t) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\pi}, & s^2+t^2 < 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$$f_{|X_1|, |X_2|}(s,t) = \begin{cases}\frac{4}{\pi}, & 0<s<1; 0<t<\sqrt{1-s^2}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
But what to do next and how to find $f_{X_1^2, X_2^2}(s,t)?$
I will be grateful for any tips as I'm stuck with this exercise.

Comment: Let $Z_1 = |X_1|$ and $Z_2 = |X_2|.$ Your computation of $f_{Z_1, Z_2}$ is correct. The reason for the hint is that at first sight you would want to compute $f_{Y_1, Y_2}$ from $f_{X_1, X_2}$ via the change of variables formula, but that requires a one-to-one map between $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(Y_1, Y_2).$ Instead, they want you to get around this by seeing that you can easily work out $f_{Z_1, Z_2}$ and we *do* have a one-to-one map between $(Z_1, Z_2) $ and $(Y_1, Y_2),$ so we can apply to change of variables formula with that instead.